# Villagers won't breed - plenty of food, fully traded

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Me and my friend have build an underground base underneath deep ocean biome. We replaced the entire seafloor with glass and removed all stone etc. all the way down to bedrock where we've build a village.. We have +10 villagers atm. that we bred on the surface above ground and moved them underground afterwards - we used an infinite breeder by this principle:

> **Breeding indefinitely**
>
> There is also a bug or glitch where the villagers can be coaxed to breed indefinitely without regard to the population cap.
>
> Villagers need to be inside a sphere (radius = village radius) around the village center in order to breed. But the village population counts only villagers that are inside a box (width, length = 2× village radius, height: 9 [always!]) around the village center. So with a sphere that can grow to any size, and a box that's always only 9 high, it should be apparent that there are some zones only covered by the sphere (above and below the village center).
>
> You can reproduce/abuse this behavior by building 6 houses on the ground level (enough to set the villager limit to 2), drop 2 (or more) villagers into a 6 blocks deep hole, and leave one villager at the top to keep the houses "alive". The villagers in the hole will breed indefinitely, because they're not counted against the cap.

I researched everything about villagers mechanics and breeding, and the houses etc. we built are recognized by the villagers since they keep using them at night.

Since our villagers wouldn't breed naturally and we wanted more villagers I tried to set up the infinite breeder again, but this time under sea/ground. However despite making sure I placed all of the 6 doors within 5 blocks of direct connection to sky (we build a glass tower through the water) the villagers still won't breed. The only difference is the farm is under the sea - but the with a glass tower it has direct connection to the sky and shouldn't think there is any problems

We've traded with them countless times, given them STACKS and STACKS of food like potatoes, carrots and bread, yet they never get any hearts and make that sweet sweet villager love and give us more babbies. For all I know they should be in full willingness to breed, but just won't enter mating mode.

I've removed every single door there is within 70 blocks each direction. If we have to we can build the infinite villager breeder above ground again, but I'd rather not since it would be so much cooler to have it underground.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that for a set of doors to be counted as a 'village' by the game code it has to have no blocks above the houses obstructing the sky. download the Minecraft [Village Info](http://chunkbase.com/mods/village-info) mod and check whether your 'village' actually counts as a village

Comment: Source of glitch please

Comment: Try building a "tunnel" of glass up to the sky - ie with a hollow centre and glass walls

Comment: @Robotnik
Village Info mod doesn't work in SMP so I can't check..
I did check in a SSP by building a house under water and it should work with a 1x1 glass to the surface as glass isn't counted as opaque in minecraft. It said that it was counted as a house. This is also what we have in our village.. We even have some that is directly open to the sky..

Comment: @ArceusMaster0493 - http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Tutorials/Village_mechanics#Breeding_indefinitely

Comment: @JonStory - Already have that in every house. The villager run inside of them every night so they should count as houses.

Comment: Sounds like you're building an Evil Villain Lair!

Answer (score 2):

Your villagers need a village to breed.  A wooden door will only count as a house if one side of it is "outside", which is to say has nothing but air blocks above some block within 5 meters.

So you could fix this be building a chimney though the ocean above every door.

Comment: Glass is not opaque in minecraft.. There is a "chimney" of glass to the  surface so technically there should be direct sky to the house/door

Comment: Glass, whilst not opaque, still counts as a **solid** block, you need air between the door & sky. Try making a 3x3 chimney of glass with air in the middle block

Answer (score 2):

The issue is not that there's no chimney, or sky above..

The issue is that the game counts sky by counting light levels.. Eventually if you are too far down, the light will dissipate whether you actually have clear access to the sky or not won't matter.

These become ineffective once you go down 15 blocks of the top level.